# Почему при передаче php переменной в скрипт данные кодируются в uft-8?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, кодировка, woocommerce

Вопрос не из простых.

Касается он настройки платежной системы в интернет-магазине `woocommerce`. Проблема заключается в следующем: данные переменной **php** (почтовый адрес) передаются в скрипт почему-то закодированными.

Для начала получаю данные поля email введенные пользователем. С помощью var_dump проверяю, что в переменной содержится верная информация (email *o4137889@nwytg.net*), но при передаче переменной внутрь скрипта

`accountId: '<?=$order->billing_email?>'`

получаю вот такую закодированную строку в **utf-8**
`accountId: '&#x6f;4&#x31;&#x33;7&#x38;&#x38;9&#x40;&#x6e;w&#x79;&#x74;g&#x2e;&#x6e;e&#x74;'`,

Причем, не важно выводится ли она через сокращенные `<?= ?>` или `<?php ?>` и `echo`

`accountId: '<?php echo $billing_email ?>'`,

, через переменную или напрямую - результат каждый раз идентичен.

С чем это может быть связано и как исправить?

```
global $woocommerce;            
$order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
var_dump($order->billing_email); //o4137889@nwytg.net

<script src="https://widget.cloudpayments.ru/bundles/cloudpayments"></script>
<script>
    var widget = new cp.CloudPayments();
        widget.<?=$widget_f?>({ // options              <!-- /////////////???????????????  -->
        publicId: '<?=$this->public_id?>',  //id из личного кабинета
        description: 'Оплата заказа <?=$order_id?>', //назначение
        amount: <?=$order->get_total()?>, //сумма
        currency: '<?=$this->currency?>', //валюта
        invoiceId: <?=$order_id?>, //номер заказа 
        accountId: '<?=$order->billing_email?>', //идентификатор плательщика
        data: <?php echo (($this->kassa_enabled == 'yes') ? json_encode($kassa_array) : "{}") ?>
                    },
    function (options) { // success
        window.location.replace('<?=$this->get_return_url($order)?>');
    },
    function (reason, options) { // fail
        window.location.replace('<?=$order->get_cancel_order_url()?>');
        }
);
</script>
```

Сервер находится на unix под управлением **vesta cp** с *php версией 7.2*

Comment: Показанная вами строка не имеет никакого отношения к utf-8. Это ASCII-символы, экранированные для html/xml

Comment: Покажите в браузере исходный html-код страницы, на которой вы выводите ваш var_dump

Comment: @andreymal вы про шапку? вот она тогда 

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru-RU" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
</head>`

Comment: @andreymal а можно как-то декодировать эти ASCII символы? Прикол в том, что все остальные настройки выводит корректно, к примеру даже `$order_id` где хранится email
`invoiceId: <?=$order_id?>, //номер заказа`

Comment: Не про шапку, а про то место в html-коде, куда выводит этот самый var_dump

Comment: я здесь разместил с расшифровкой `var_dump($order);`
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/13b6daa43cddf5527a2745e8b06c76070a0207d4

Comment: Возможно я слепой, но вывода var_dump для billing_email я там не нашёл

Comment: @andreymal потому что я его исключил и теперь стал тестировать с `var_dump($order);`
var_dump для billing_email выводится вот так
string(18) “o4137889@nwytg.net”, т.е. там как и положено - 18 показывает символов, не 78 как можно было подумать

Comment: Тогда это всё действительно очень странно

Comment: Пробую декодировать:
`<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($order_billing_email, ENT_NOQUOTES); ?>`
преобразует чуть лучше - первые 3 и последние 2 символа расшифровал по сравнению с изначальной записью
`accountId: 'o41&#51;&#x37;&#x38;&#x38;&#x39;&#64;nw&#121;&#x74;&#x67;&#x2e;&#x6e;et',`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С большим трудом, но удалось отыскать причину - поделюсь с вами, может быть кому-нить пригодится. Есть такая зараза плагин [Email Address Encoder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/email-address-encoder/)

> (A lightweight plugin that protects email addresses from
>   email-harvesting robots by encoding them into decimal and hexadecimal
>   entities.)

Вот он как раз и виноват во всем! Отключил - и все заработало!